# Caching viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, caching, viewstate

[ViewState Caching](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncachepoint/viewstate-caching.html)

This is a great idea, but it's implemented for SharePoint. Wonder if there is a solution for regular asp.net pages, which does the same, caches viewstates.

Comment: This is quite tricky. What would you do if your server is quite busy (so there are many users whose page view state is being cached) and your view state cache expires before you post back your form?

Comment: @Robert just use a cache or persistence medium that doesn't expire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually quite simple! You just need to override these two methods on your page:

```
SavePageStateToPersistentMedium()

LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
```

In there, you can get the ViewState object tree, serialize it however you want and store it wherever you want (Session, SQL, etc), and instead of returning the entire serialized blob to the browser, just return a unique ID you can use to look it up again next time around.

The idea is covered in painstaking detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible through overriding the below two methods in

```
asp.net System.Web.UI.Page:

SavePageStateToPersistentMedium()

LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
```

While in the first method you need to check if the ViewState already exists in the cache and if not save it there, in the second method you can retrieve it if it is already there.

You can concatenate the SessionID and the pageName as the key for the cache viewStateKey.